# Function inside a function is only called once

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am trying to do a coding exercise which consists in playing snake and ladders between 2 players, so in the play function i try to use another function to advance or decrease the player if they land in a ladder or snake, it works once with player 1, but not after that turn:

```
class SnakesLadders():

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_player = "1"
        self.player1_counter = 0
        self.player2_counter = 0
        
        
    def play(self, die1, die2):
        def get_value(current_square):
            ladders_snakes_dict = {2:38, 7:14, 8:31, 15:26, 21:42, 28:84, 51:67, 71:91, 78:98, 
                                   15:6, 46:25, 49:11, 62:19, 64:60, 74:53, 89:68, 92:88, 95:75, 99:80}
            for key, value in ladders_snakes_dict.items():
                if current_square == key:
                    return value
                else:
                    return current_square
        
        if self.current_player == "1":
            self.player1_counter += (die1 + die2)
            self.player1_counter = get_value(self.player1_counter)
            
            player_position = "Player " + self.current_player + " is on square " + str(self.player1_counter)
            
            if die1 == die2:
                self.current_player = "1"
            else:
                self.current_player = "2"
            
            return player_position
            
                
        elif self.current_player == "2":
            self.player2_counter += (die1 + die2)
            self.player2_counter = get_value(self.player2_counter)
            
            player_position = "Player " + self.current_player + " is on square " + str(self.player2_counter)
            
            if die1 == die2:
                self.current_player = "2"
            else:
                self.current_player = "1"
            
            return player_position
```

The tests return:

```
 Should return: 'Player 1 is on square 38' Correct

 Should return: 'Player 1 is on square 44' Correct

 Should return: 'Player 2 is on square 31'
'Player 2 is on square 8' should equal 'Player 2 is on square 31'

 Should return: 'Player 1 is on square 25'
'Player 1 is on square 46' should equal 'Player 1 is on square 25'
```

Comment: Since you used `if` and `elif`, once player 1 is matched only the first `if` block is run. Player 2 is completely ignored. There is no loop or anything that instructs the code to keep playing after one iteration of `play()` is completed.

Comment: Im doing this at a coding exercise site called codewars.com, you input the code and they have a set of tests that run that code multiple times, as you can see i showed the tests results below the code and on the 4th one it is also using player 1, but it doesnt use the function.

Comment: That doesn't help, you need to make adjustments to your own code

Comment: I will add tomorrow the exercise link because i dont have it on my cellphone so you can visualize what i mean.

Comment: you show what tests return but you didn't show what result you expected ? We don't have access to this exercide so we can't see expected result and you have to add all information in question. BTW: Use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed. Maybe your function is executed but with different values then you expect.

Comment: i thik your function has big mistake `else: return current_square` which is executed on first item in list and it will not check other elements. You have to use `return current_square` after `for`-loop when it checked all elements on list.

Comment: furas, on the last part it shows what it was expected: 'Player 2 is on square 8' should equal 'Player 2 is on square 31', nonetheless you are right the issue is with the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

As for me all your problem makes

```
 else:
     return current_square
```

inside `for`-loop which is executed on first element but you should run it after loop when all elements are checked

```
for key, value in ladders_snakes_dict.items():
    if current_square == key:
        return value

# after `for`-loop        
return current_square
```

---

**BTW:** you can write it without `for`-loop

```
if current_square in ladders_snakes_dict:
    return ladders_snakes_dict[current_square]

return current_square
```

Or you can use `.get(key, default_value)`

```
return ladders_snakes_dict.get(current_square, current_square)
```

---

**BTW:** I see one mistake in dictionary - you have `15:26` and `15:6` but dictionary can't keep two elements with the same key so you will have only last one `15:6`. You have mistake in one key. Game can't have `ladder` and `snake` in the same field `15`

Comment: Thank you!! yes that was the issue, after that i had to solve other stuff, but thanks  and yes i had a typo on the dictionart, but thanks for everything.